# What is the weight limit on pergo flooring?

Tags: flooring

We currently have pergo installed in our kitchen/dining room and have had it for a number of years - no complaints.  We are now faced with the issue of pulling up carpet in the living room/hall as it has met its life cycle. We live in a mobile home and the carpet apparently was not installed properly when we had it done as it buckled and looks terrible and we have had to live with it for too long.  I don't want carpeting again if this is going to happen again. We were thinking of pergo but have furniture that is very heavy and want to know what kind of weight pergo will withstand.  Any ideas?

Comment: There are no weight limits on flooring that I have heard of. I don't think there is any furniture that is too heavy for Pergo flooring.

Comment: Technically, isn't the OP's concern more about ***pressure*** than weight?  I've certainly seen flooring with cautions about, say, stiletto heels, or golf cleats...

Comment: As floating floors expand/contract with temperature & humidity, I'd suspect that a heavy object near a wall, that might pin down a given a section and not allow it to move is going to be more problematic than one in the middle of the room.  Two heavy objects would also be problematic.

Comment: It's been quite a while now... what gap did you use? Has the floor buckled with humidity changes? What climate range are you in (how much humidity swing do you get year-round)?

Answer (score 1):

It can basically take any amount of weight.  Well I am sure there might be a theoretical limit but nothing you are going to possibly have will effect it.  The key is to allow for some minor expansion gaps on your out walls and to never nail/screw/whatever anything into the flooring.

You have to make sure that no cabinets, shelves, or anything else that is anchored to the floor.  Other than that you are good to go in a mobile home.  The only issues I have seen with Pergo is when people screw down an island on top of it or very large rooms - 20 feet plus squared.

Comment: I'm guessing that the company my neighbor had redo their kitchen had no clue -- they insisted we put the floor down, then put the cabinets on top of it.  I'm starting to wonder if the damage to the floor is caused by that, rather than our assumption that the time one of his kids decided to 'mop' the floor and left standing water for at least an hour before an adult realized.

Comment: @Joe - those cabinets should **never** have been installed on top of Pergo. The flooring should have stopped 3/4" from the cabinets, then the kicks installed to cover the gap. As installed, the flooring is guaranteed to buckle.

Comment: Standard expansion gap is 3/8", not 3/4".

Comment: @Doresoom - usually we do 1/4" with 3/8" for larger areas.

Comment: DMoore, Absolutely - I just did a 10'x11' room with 1/4" gaps. The instructions said 3/8" but I figured it would be fine for a smaller room, just as you mention. Both are a far cry from @TDHofstetter's suggestion of 3/4" though, which will severely limit the selection of base molding.

Comment: Well I try to never use quarter round.  I go with 1/2" baseboards and they cover pretty much any gap I would leave.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Pergo specifically, but a found a [website that gives details about weight issues on floating floors](http://kronotexusa.com/blog/bid/248363/Laminate-Flooring-Weight-Limits-Heavyweight-Issues-and-Solutions)

Although they give a guideline that anything over 500lb is a problem, they specifically call out washing machines (listed at 175lb) and treadmills (250-300lb) as being an issue.  They also mention things with small feet that concentrate the force at only a few points.

They do have a solution for some items -- they recommend for pool tables and pianos, where you're going to keep them in a fixed location, that you isolate that section of the floor from the rest:

> For instance, if you know you're going to park that baby grand piano you inherited from your aunt on top of your Kronotex USA Beaufort floor, install an "island" or "lilly pad" of the same flooring where the piano legs will go, separated by the rest of the room's flooring, with the standard T-molding and expansion gaps. That way the weight of the piano is literally isolated to the piano's footprint without putting the rest of your floor at risk.

Unfortunately, this likely won't work with couches and such.  You also run into the problem that it may not be just the weight of the couch, but also the weight of the people on the couch ... especially if it has feet that concentrate the load in small areas.